# How to skip blank table rows and randomly show null rows only

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a website with a members section where users can include an affiliate link in their profile. The home page of the website should show one affiliate link at a time, rotating through users which have set an affiliate link. My server is running `php5.6`.

I've tried using `rand()` with `IS NOT NULL` to select users from the website's SQL database in a few ways:

```
SELECT * FROM users IS NOT NULL ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1;
```

but I get an error. I also have tried

```
SELECT leads ORDER by rand() FROM users IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Still no results.

```
SELECT * FROM users IS NOT NULL  LIMIT 1;
```

It works but it will not randomly select through the null data.

I keep getting the following errors:

> ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT * FROM users IS NOT NULL ORDER
>   by rand() LIMIT 1. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IS NOT NULL ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1' at line 1

and below this does not give an error but it does not do what I need it to do.

```
SELECT leads IS NOT NULL FROM users ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Instead of reordering `FROM` and `ORDER BY` why don't you read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with checking NOT NULL. You have to check NULL in WHERE clause and also by specific column name. You can add 1 or Multiple or even All columns in the WHERE clause as per your requirement. Please try as below-

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE column_name1 IS NOT NULL 
AND column_name2 IS NOT NULL 
-- You can add here more columns 
-- using AND or OR depending on what you wants to check.
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```